# How to display a page only for the first time in qml

Tags: authentication, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I want to only display the login screen if users are logging in for the first time (server-side program Check login data). if they exit out and reopen the program they should directly redirect to main screen.

How to display login screen only for the first time in Qt Quick?

Comment: Take a look at [Settings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html)

Comment: thanks. it helped.